# struts 2 jquery grid - editGridRow on double click on subgrid row not showing data

Tags: jqgrid

I am using struts2 jquery grid 3.1.0 version. I have requirement to display the row details on double click. I use the following code to display the edited row. But the dialog shows up an empty dialog on double click. Any help on this would be appreciated. The code is attached below

```
        var parentSelRow = jQuery(gridFn.$id).jqGrid('getGridParam',
                'selrow');
        var grid = $(gridFn.$id);
        var gridSub = $(gridFn.$id + "_" + parentSelRow + "_table");
        gridSub.dblclick(function(e) {
            var td = e.target;
            var ptr = $(td, gridSub[0].rows).closest("tr.jqgrow");
            if ($(ptr).length === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            var ri = ptr[0].rowIndex;
            var ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(td);
            var rowId = $(ptr).attr("id");
            alert(rowId);
            var selectedRow = gridSub.jqGrid('getGridParam', ('selrow'));
            if (selectedRow != null && selectedRow.length > 0) {
                gridSub.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowId, {
                    editCaption : "View Record",
                    width : 660,
                    recreateForm : true,
                    recreateFilter : true,
                    viewPagerButtons : true,
                    onInitializeForm : gridFn.initializeViewForm,
                    beforeShowForm : gridFn.beforeViewForm,
                    afterShowForm : gridFn.afterViewForm,
                    onClose : gridFn.onCloseViewForm,
                    closeAfterAdd : true,
                    closeOnEscape : true,
                    errorTextFormat : gridFn.errorTextFormat});     }
```